# Azure Devops Pipeline returning: 'Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Internal Server Error (CODE: 500)'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use Azure DevOps pipelines to build a .NET 5 (Core) web app and deploy it to my Azure app service. I can't find any complete examples in the documentation that achieve this so I'm following this:

https://github.com/shahedc/NetLearnerApp/blob/main/azure-pipelines.yml.txt

However, the Azure deploy task keeps returning this vague error:
[image]

In my Azure portal I only get this error:
[image]

I am assuming the issue is in my pipeline because deployment works when I deploy it directly from the Deployment Center in the Azure portal. Here are the details for the 3 relevant tasks my pipeline:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In "package or folder" give the full zip (your artifact name ) instead of wild card.

Comment: Are there any ip restrictions on the app service?

Comment: @blockingHD Nope

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found the solution. It turns out the issue was not in the pipeline, but was caused by a Git connection to the app service I had previously set up in the Azure Deployment Center. Even though I disconnected/removed this Git connection, there was somehow still a residual file left over in Azure that was causing the error. I deleted the 'deployments' folder in Kudu (pictured below) and the pipeline started working as expected.

[image]

Getting to the above pictured view:

- Navigate to your Azure Function project
- Search for Advanced Tools
- Open PowerShell

Comment: Okay, so, what is Kudu and how do I reach it from Azure? (I have the same symptoms)

Comment: @Qwertie I edited the post and added steps to get to the pictured screen.

Comment: Thank you, worked for me as well! Seems that this also applies when moving the az func deploy from one Azure subscription to another.

Answer (score 10):

Check if you have disk space available.

Yesterday we started getting this error, even if we tried to re-deploy packages that were successfully deployed just an hour before. Our system guys checked and found out that we reached the space limit and that it was time to upgrade.

P.S. I know that this was answered a long time ago. I am just sharing the solution that was not mentioned here and that worked for us.

Comment: Thank you @GritKit for posting this. You saved me a bunch of time when I hit the same issue as you and was headed down the dreaded Azure rabbit hole. I had added a 2nd app service to an existing Free (F1) app service plan. Everything was fine until the application grew in complexity and pushed disk space over the 1GB limit.
For those interested, I found the disk space usage by clicking "Quotas" under the "App Service plan" section of the failing app service's blade in Portal,. Then clicked the blue inconspicuous "File system usage" link. The chart showed me pegged at 1GB consumed.

Answer (score 0):

think what Dan Beaulieu said in above answers is correct, but one thing to add, in my case, after deleting the deployments folder, remember to **restart the app service/web app**, which will make it take effect.