# Azure DevOps Pipeline failure: missing 'deployments' directory in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, deployment, permissions, kudu

I'm experiencing an issue with my Azure DevOps pipeline similar to the one discussed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67453259/azure-devops-pipeline-returning-failed-to-deploy-web-package-to-app-service-i). The solution in the thread suggests deleting the 'deployment' directory in Azure, but I'm unable to find this directory in my setup.

Context: I am working with an Azure Web Application and trying to deploy through Azure DevOps. I encountered a problem where the deployment fails, resembling the issue described in the linked Stack Overflow question.

Problem: Following the advice in the thread, I attempted to locate and delete the 'deployments' directory in my Azure App Service using Kudu. However, I couldn't find this directory. I'm not sure if it's a permission issue or if the directory is hidden or missing.

Attempts:

- I've checked the Kudu console and file structure but couldn't locate the 'deployments' folder.
- I also tried looking for any hidden files or system directories but had no luck.

Questions:

- Why might the 'deployments' folder be missing in my Azure App Service environment?
- Is there a way to restore or recreate this folder if it's necessary for deployment?
- Could this issue be related to user permissions, and if so, how can I verify and adjust them accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating your Web App with **`F1 tier`** your application will only be available for 60 minutes per day also the compute size will be less. You can utilize Basic or Standard Tier application

[image]

I tried deploying a **.Net application** via `Azure DevOps` and it succeeded without any errors like below:-

**My Azure DevOps yaml pipeline that builds and Deploys a .Net app:-**

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: 'publishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - download: current
    artifact: 'publishedApp'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'xxxx subscription (xxxxxxx6e97cb2a7)'
      appType: 'webApp'
      appName: 'silicon-webapp980'
      package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Deployments Folder is present:-***

```
https://webapp-name0.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole
```

***Visit Folder - site > deployments > all the Deployments logs are present here. you can also add your `Startup.sh` script with startup command in your deployments folder***

By default only tools folder will be present inside deployments folder, After deployment the Logs will also be added.

[image]

If deployments folder is not present inside the site folder you can create it manually:-

**/site > Click + > New Folder > deployments**

[image]

Ideally the deployments folder inside site folder should be created by default, If it is not created or deleted create it manually or deploy a new Web app.

I also created another Deployment with Free Tier, Even when the deployments folder was not present earlier, It got added automatically after the deployment.