# Can't find loc string for key: KuduStackTraceURL

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, continuous-integration, devops

I have been trying to deploy my function app code since yesterday and nothing worked. The pipeline shown below is the one auto-generated by azure devops, it should work. I have tried several aproaches, even executen az commands which didnt work neither. I paste below the pipeline code.

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: |
          $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionApp
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

I get these errors constantly :

[image]

Some one has faced this ? I saw a lot of threads talking about this but none solved my problem

My functionapp code is written in c#

I tried everything i found on internet but nothing worked

Comment: I found the solution. I will share it here so maybe its helpful for some one else

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67460495/20538377

Comment: @AntonioCampuzanoMartinez It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.

Comment: Hi @NaveenSharma I used the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67460495/20538377.