# Azure DevOps pipeline release fails with error - No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117244/azure-devops-pipeline-release-error-no-package-found-with-specified-pattern-d), but was not successful.

I have an ASP.NET Core App Service (Web App) in Azure DevOps repository and the release over that builds always fails with this error:

> Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip

I'm pretty new to CI for App Services and not sure if I'm missing a step in my YAML or CI Build?

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: SDL
    jobs:
    - job: SDLTools
      pool:
        name: Azure-Pipelines-EO-Windows2022-Office
      steps:
      - task: ms.vss-governance-buildtask.governance-build-task-component-detection.ComponentGovernanceComponentDetection@0
        condition: |
          and(
            eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'),
            ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
          )
        displayName: 'Component Detection'
      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
          includeRootFolder: true
          archiveType: 'zip'
          archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
          replaceExistingArchive: true        
      - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
        inputs:
          ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
          azureSubscription: 'Subscription'
          appType: 'webApp'
          WebAppName: 'MyWebAppName'
          package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/*.zip'
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

I see that the archive compleete

```
D:\a\_work\_tasks\ArchiveFiles_35346534345f\2.231.0\7zip\7z.exe a -tzip -mx=5 D:\a\_work\1\a\26395403.zip @D:\a\_work\_temp\v6pxdmipzc
```

But then fails during the deploy.

```
No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\_work\1\s\*.zip<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you observe the path of the archive (`D:\a\_work\1\a\26395403.zip`) and the path in the error message (`D:\a\_work\1\s\*.zip`) when deployment fails, there is a difference after the part `D:\a\_work\1\`.

That's because the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` used while archiving the file is a different directory compared to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` used for picking up the zip while deploying the app.

So use the `package` location in `AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4` task as `'$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.zip'` in order for the agent to find the archived file.

```
.
.
.      
      - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
        inputs:
          ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
          azureSubscription: 'Subscription'
          appType: 'webApp'
          WebAppName: 'MyWebAppName'
          package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.zip'
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped and got me a different error `Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Internal Server Error (CODE: 500)`

Comment: Closing the loop on this, but I figured out the 500 error with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67453259/azure-devops-pipeline-returning-failed-to-deploy-web-package-to-app-service-i